# Using Excel Indirect with worksheet names

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets and have developed in the some of the worksheets a query/reference to a row in one of the worksheets.

I realized that when I add a row to the referenced worksheet, the query/reference does not realize that the new row has been added. I don't understand why, but be that as it may, I have found some references to a function called INDIRECT that seems to solve this issue.  Does it?

I have tried to figure out how to reference a separate worksheet in the formula but can't seem to get it to work.  The current reference is:  `='B&A'!P41` where `B&A` is the worksheet name and `P41` is the referenced cell.

So here are two questions:

1. Will INDIRECT solve my problem when I add a new line to `B&A`?
2. If so, what is the correct syntax for the INDIRECT function?

Comment: If you consider the answer below to be suitable, then please click the gray tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `INDIRECT` will enforce it always looking at the same cell, regardless of other cells being added/removed.

`INDIRECT` takes a string, which it then will use as a cell address. As such, your current formula of:

```
='B&A'!P41
```

would become

```
=INDIRECT("'B&A'!P41")
```

Using this, it should reference the cell statically and only update if the cell referenced changes.

Comment: Well, that seemed to work for the row, but I was hoping to copy that formula down all the rows.  It didn't work.  How come and is there a way to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add NEW lines/cells/columns in the referenced sheet you have to create a way for the referring formulas to recognize this.

I'd create a cell in the referenced sheet to contain a table/array reference as text
*- e.g. `$A1:$B200` in a named cell, e.g. `table_ref` -*
which then can be picked up and dereferenced (from other sheets) with an extra INDIRECT() as in `INDIRECT( INDIRECT(table_ref) )`

In creating the contents of `table_ref` you may have to use `CELLS()`, `COUNTIF()`, `SUBTOTAL()`, `OFFSET()`, `ROWS()` or similar functions, and concatenate the results from several of them - I believe there are a few more similar functions that I can't remember now.